# Visual Studios build C++ in background?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++

Is there a way to have visual studios build my C++ project in the background every few seconds?

Note: I generate code using another tool so if i don't need to be in visual studios to kick off the build then great
`

Comment: Using MSBuild with scheduled tasks is one way. There's no way in the IDE that I know of (it would be a user interface nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

The VC project file .vcxproj is actually a MSBuild project file. You can open a command window and run "MSBuild ". Use Scheduled tasks if you want to repeat it in the given intervals.

If some other project depends on this one you're building, add MSBuild command to the Pre-Build events.